# Run Python script On Heroku or DG Ocean when click button on web

Tags: python, php, selenium, heroku, digital-ocean

Is it possible to run python script, which I will upload on Heroku or DG Ocean droplet (depending on which of them is most comfortable for what I am trying to do), from external website button?
My scenario: I have scrapper and I want to run it when user clicks on button on my webpage, so scrapper will scrape current data and will show it to user. Is it possible to do? or if we have any other way?

Comment: _"Is it possible to do?"_ - Sure, it's possible. Where _exactly_ are you stuck? Post your code/attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thanks for response and suggestions. But, it is first time that i have to run myapp from website, so i have no any single line of code, i even do not know ifit is possible to do, so i have no code to paste in my question. it is just question and need your suggestions.

Comment: As I said, it's possible. Please make sure you've done the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) so you can make some attempts yourself first. If you then get stuck on something _specific_ along the way, come back and explain the issue. We're here to help you if you get stuck, but we're not here to write it all for you (which a proper answer here would require us to). Questions that are just like "is it possible" or "point me in the right direction" are not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

For others, who will have same things in the feature:  So, i am going to make FLASK app to use DG Droplet or Heroku, after i will import Flask app using Iframe in my Web project and use only BUTTON, like this i will use my scraper on my Webpage.

Thanks